# Do search engines penalize for using the incorrect top level domain?

Tags: seo

I am setting up a site that ends with .me , although it has nothing to do with montenegro.

Will search engines heavily penalize me for this?

Thanks

Comment: You don't seem to quite understand what the country-specific TLDs are for.

Comment: I was being serious. Your assumption seems to be that country-specific TLDs are meant to be *about* that country, but that's not the case -- originally they were meant for people and companies *from* that country. If a Montenegrin puts up a .me site about, say, bicycling, it's a perfectly legitimate use of the domain but the content has nothing to do with Montenegro itself. Nowadays just about everyone uses whatever TLD they please, even search engines - goo.gl doesn't have only Greenlandic pages and youtu.be doesn't show only Belgian videos.

Comment: Genuinely useful comments, thanks. So I guess the answer is 'no I wont be penalised'?

Comment: Yeah, it's extremely unlikely.

Comment: I've no reason to doubt what you say vis-a-vis search engines, although in my experience registering domains is not as liberal as you suggest. To get a '.fr' name last year was a bureaucratic nightmare, I had to get my French girlfriend's mother to register it, with her credit card and her French address. So my original question was not unreasonable, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not.  There are plenty of sites that use a .me domain, that have nothing to do with Montenegro and contain useful information for a global audience.  This could also be said for .co.uk and .de and many others.

Search engines know this and therefore would be foolish to assume in their ranking algorithms that the TLD would indicate localised content for that specific area.